# How can I pass messages between two instances of *the same* Google Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, messaging, p2p

While Google Chrome's [messaging API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) allows communication between two different extensions using their 'Extension ID', I'm yet to see the issue of communication between two instances of the *same* extension be addressed. Is this possible using the current Google Chrome API? Is there an 'Instance ID' to uniquely identify each instance of my extension?

If not, I think I will try using my own server be the -middle man- and let all the instances of my extension talk to each other using my -middle man-. In that case, does the Chrome API expose the *Instance ID* for extensions? If not, any advice on coming up with my own Instance ID scheme?

Comment: One pitfall is that when the documents mention an optional argument, you omit that argument (don't pass undefined in its place). For example, chrome.extensions.connect(extensionId, connectInfo) is simply chrome.extensions.connect(connectInfo) to connect to your own extension. If you still need help, you need to get your terminology right. What does an "instance" mean? What pages are you running (background, views, content)?

Comment: Instance of an extension is simply multiple copies. For example, if _you_ install the Adblock extension and _I_ install the Adblock extension too, then that's 2 *instances* of the the same Adblock extension. My question is how can I get these two instances of Adblock to talk to each other, as both your copy and my copy of Adblock have the same ID of *gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom* and any message I send using that ID will reach my instance of Adblock, not yours.

Comment: I'm trying out a user-login based approach to get the instances to talk to each other. This means, using the example above, you will login to Adblock using your credentials & I'll do the same at my end; both the Adblock instances will then use these unique credentials to communicate. I'll have to use my own server to manage the conns which is rather cumbersome for the task at hand, so I very much welcome a better, more elegant approach that can get the job done. As for what elements I'm using, so far it's limited to views and content scripts but I'll have to use option pages etc, when I ship.

Answer (score 1):

you can certainly do that, I have done the same thing for my Reload All Tabs extension.
https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/bfenodnbilondijnaionekngdhadmegk

Basically, you would need an "extension ID" what I did, I basically uploaded the main extension to the gallery, which gave me the unique ID.

With that ID, you can send requests to that extension via:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-sendRequest

And listen through external extension requests through:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#event-onRequestExternal

You can take a look at the source code for Reload All Tabs, to see how it is done:
https://github.com/mohamedmansour/reload-all-tabs-extension

Comment: I'm afraid what I'm looking for is a little different. For instance, assuming that both of us have 'Reload All Tabs' extension installed( quite a handy extension btw ), is it possible for *you* to reload all the tabs of *my* Chrome remotely, via *your* copy of Reload All Tabs running on *your* Chrome?

Comment: To do "remote" extension communication is not possible with the current API. The only way you can do it is through a middle man. Where that middle layer would accept commands and route it to the other user. Such communication is called Publish-Subscriber, you could do a one to one communication as well. But a middle man should route all messages. You could have a WebSocket server too, that both clients connect to. But Cross Extension communication is only used within extensions installed locally not externally.